# Capturing group with optional start and end characters

Tags: php, regex

i have the follow string: `find me String1\String2\String3`, so i wanna capture string1, 2 and 3 if they exist. String 3 can be optional.

So far, what i could make is: `(?<=find me)\s(\\?[\w]+\\?){1,3}`, my assumption was:

- The string should have `find me`at the beggining but it should not be captured
- a whitespace
- a group with `\` as optional character at the beggining of the string, a word following it and `\`at the end of it, optional too, it can appear from 1 to 3 times.

What is wrong with my regex pattern?

Comment: What is your regex flavor?

Comment: Only the last match i.e. `String3` will be available in your 2nd capturing group.

Comment: @anubhava i actually dont know, i'm doing it with php.

Comment: ok PHP is PCRE and `\G` is supported to my answer should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your regex flavor supports `\G`, you can use this regex to capture all 3 strings separately:

```
(?<=find me |(?<!^)\G\\)\w+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dMZYWo/2)

`\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match.

`\G` matches a position that either line start OR end of the previous match. In this case I also have a negative lookbehind `(?<!^)` which means don't match line start, hence it makes `\G` match only the positions that end of the previous matches. For your example, it matches twice i.e. end of `String1` and end of `String2`.

Comment: Could you explain me this: (?<!^)\G\\`. I couldnt understand what it really does.

Comment: `\G` matches a position that either line start OR end of the previous match. In this case I also have a negative lookbehind `(?<!^)` which means don't match line start, hence it makes `\G` match only the positions that end of the previous matches. For your example it matches twice i.e. end of `String1` and end of `String2`.